# Multiple error notifications

Tags: java, android

I have a registration page where the user has to enter personal information about themselves, if something entered is invalid then error notifications should pop up

```
if (!PhoneNumber.startsWith("055") || !PhoneNumber.startsWith("050") || !PhoneNumber.startsWith("056") || !PhoneNumber.startsWith("052")) {
        // does not match
        contact_number.setError("Please enter a valid phone number");
        return;
    }

    if (TextUtils.isEmpty(password) )
    {
        VendorRegPassword.setError("Please enter your password");
        return;
    }
    else if (password.length() < 6)
    {
        VendorRegPassword.setError("Please use more than 6 characters");
        return;
    }

    if (TextUtils.isEmpty(email) || !email.contains("@") )
    {
        VendorRegEmail.setError("Please enter a valid email address");
    }
```

Independently they work on their own but when put together it does not work properly, also the phone number error does not work properly, can somebody help me with this?

Comment: what is the current status? is it working or not?

Comment: @Kaushal28 working perfectly

Comment: If my answer was helpful, you can accept it :)

Answer (score 1):

They are not working together properly because you are returning from the method in `if` or `else if`conditions. Remove `return` statements from `if` and `else`. Because `return` will terminate the execution of method, so further code will never be executed due to `return`.

They are working separately because, there is no need to execute further conditions (no further conditions at all), so returning from method seems correct solution.

Comment: Nice precise answer. And works well with the companion I just put up ;-)

Comment: @Kaushal28 once I removed the returns it just makes the app crash

Comment: @Kaushal28 too long to send

Comment: @Dckw24 you can edit the question and post logs there.

Answer (score 1):

The other answer is correct; the `return` statement simply prevents all checks to be executed. And in *this* case, you want all validations to take place, as each validation has a **different** way of informing the user about the problem.

Beyond that: from a "clean code" perspective you should be careful to simply stuff **all** validations into the same poor method. Instead: structure your code so that it clearly expresses what is going on, like:

```
private void validateAll(PhoneNumber number, Email email, Password password) {
  validatePhoneNumber(number);
  validateEmail(email);
  ...
```

and separate helpers like

```
private void validatePhoneNumber(number) {
   boolean validPrefix = false;
   for (String validPrefix : PREFEIXES) {
     if (phoneNumber.startsWith(validPrefix) {
       validPrefix = true;
     }
   }

   if (!validPrefix) {
     contact_number.setError("Please enter a valid phone number");
   }
}
```

for example. And please note - I fixed another bad practice (your idea to simply hard-code all valid prefixes). You always want to put such information into some constant set/list; so that you have exactly **one** place in your code that knows what those prefixes are.